# Travis CI - docker image not pushed to dockerhub

Tags: docker, travis-ci, dockerhub

I am new to CI with travis and I am trying to learn it by following a course. I have created a public repository in dockerhub, and pushed the project to github  with .travis.yml file. I have previously connected and authorised travis at github. The github project can be found [here](https://github.com/Drax74/Simple-express). The travis build gets triggered and it appears to be successful, but nothing is pushed to dockerhub.

You can see the build process here:

[image]

The travis build appears to be successful, but nothing is pushed to docker hub. On expanding the log I could see this message is being logged:

```
Must provide --username with --password-stdin
```

But, I have already set up the environment variables in travis as you can see below, so I don't get why I get this message?

[image]

Comment: What's the output of `docker push`?

Comment: you mean if I run it locally from my terminal?

Comment: @NickODell I have updated my question with more outputs.

Comment: @Leff Line 224 of Travis-CI output has an arrow.  That means there is more output, currently hidden, from docker push.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't realise that environment variables need to be set per project. Also I wasn't even getting the option for settings for that repository until I synced again github with travis. Once I done the syncing part one more time, the option appeared and I was able to set the variables for that repository. And then the build process went through and the image was pushed to dockerhub.